How to add a fragment to a container after all other existing views?
I have a FrameLayout that's served as a container for new fragment. Fragment will be added by fragmentTransaction.add(...). However, I have a couple of views hardcoded in the FrameLayout already. I want them to be above of the fragment. I can achieve that by setting the existing view android:translationZ but that doesn't feel the right approach. Is there a way to "insert" the fragment instead of add or anything other than hardcoding the Y value?
